# Running Median in O(log n) time in Python

Tags: python, time-complexity, median

I'm trying to find the running median of a set of numbers after each operation, where an operation can be one of the following:

**add x** - add the number x in the set of numbers

**remove x** - remove the number x from the set of numbers (assume x always exists in the set)

My goal is to perform every operation in O(log n) time. How can this be achieved in Python? Are there any built-in constructs in Python to achieve this?

If only **add x** operations are allowed, a possible algorithm is to maintain a minHeap (to store lower half of numbers) and a maxHeap (to store upper half of numbers), as explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmogG01IjYc&ab_channel=HackerRank). But if **remove x** operations are allowed too, then deletion of a value will take O(n) time (O(n) for linearly searching the value in heaps, O(log n) for performing increase/decrease key operation and popping out an element). So, how to handle deletion of values in O(log n) time?

P.S. - I know how to do this in C++ using multisets. Since they are implemented as Balanced BST, all operations (insertion, searching and deletion) are O(log n).

Comment: If you're aware that a balanced BST will give you the operation efficiency you need, why don't you use a balanced BST?

Comment: Actually, I was searching for a built-in construct in Python (updated the question now). But sure, in the worst case, one could write it oneselves.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned balanced BSTs as a possible solution, you can get your desired (worst case) time bounds from any third-party module that implements BSTs or Order Statistic trees, such as [Sorted Containers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html). This has the added benefit of already offering add, remove, and arbitrary indexing in O(log n) time.

If your question was about how to do these operations specifically with the two heap approach (i.e. a maxheap for the smaller half of numbers and a minheap for the larger half), there are two viable options for implementing remove:

1. Use a heap-type that supports Decrease-Key (e.g. Fibonnaci or Brodal heaps) and keep pointers to all of your values; this has the benefit of giving worst case O(log n) remove, but isn't available with Python's builtin [heapq library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html).
2. Use Lazy Deletion to mark elements as removed. This has the downside of making your removes only O(log n) in amortized time, and O(n) worst case, but with the benefit of using only heapq and its binary heap.

Here is a Python implementation of the minheap-maxheap approach with heapq and Lazy Deletion. The rebuilding strategy, which is similar to collision resolution for hash collisions through open addressing, is to perform a full pass over both heaps and remove all deleted elements whenever the fraction of deleted elements exceeds 50%.

```py
import collections
import heapq
import math
from typing import Union, List, Counter


class MedianHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Data structure for holding numeric types, with O(log n) amortized insertion and deletion and
        constant worst case median finding.
        Maintains two heaps:
        a max heap with values smaller than (or eq. to) the median, and a
        min heap with values larger than (or eq. to) the median).
        We use lazy deletion from heaps (rebuilding them if more than ~50% of the heaps are deleted elements)
         to guarantee amortized insertion and deletion.

        The following class invariants are maintained before an external function call starts
        and after that function call ends:
            1. The front of each heap is either infinity (the empty heap sentinel), or a valid element
            2. All elements in self.max_heap have a value less than or equal to all elements in self.min_heap
            3. Size (i.e. undeleted elements) of self.min_heap is 0 or 1 plus the size of self.max_heap"""

        self.min_heap: List[Union[int, float]] = [math.inf]  # Add a sentinel value, to avoid repeated empty checks.
        self.max_heap: List[Union[int, float]] = [math.inf]  # on the left: all elements <= effective median

        self.total_real_elems: int = 0
        self.min_real_elems: int = 0
        self.max_real_elems: int = 0

        self.deleted: Counter[int, int] = collections.Counter()

        # If lazy deletion has caused our data structures to fill too much with deleted elements, trigger a rebuild
        # We rebuild if: (lazy_deletion_multiplier * #deleted) > total_size + lazy_deletion_constant.

        # By default, the multiplier is set at 50%, as is common for open-addressing hash tables which also use
        # lazy deletion. The constant can be increased based on performance needs.
        self.lazy_deletion_multiplier: int = 2
        self.lazy_deletion_constant: int = 500

    def insert(self, num: int) -> None:
        """Insert num into our MedianHeap. May not trigger a full rebuild. O(lg n) worst case time."""
        if not (-math.inf < num < math.inf):
            raise ValueError
        if self.total_real_elems == 0:
            heapq.heappush(self.min_heap, num)
            self.total_real_elems += 1
            self.min_real_elems += 1
            return None

        if num >= self.min_heap[0]:
            heapq.heappush(self.min_heap, num)
            self.min_real_elems += 1
        else:
            heapq.heappush(self.max_heap, -num)
            self.max_real_elems += 1

        self.total_real_elems += 1
        self._rebalance()
        return None

    def remove(self, num: int) -> None:
        """Change the status of one instance of 'num' from active to deleted. O(lg n) amortized, O(n) worst case time.
        num must be an active element in our data structure. May trigger a rebuild."""
        if num >= self.min_heap[0]:
            if num == self.min_heap[0]:
                heapq.heappop(self.min_heap)
            else:
                self.deleted[num] += 1
            self.min_real_elems -= 1
        else:
            if num == -self.max_heap[0]:
                heapq.heappop(self.max_heap)
            else:
                self.deleted[num] += 1
            self.max_real_elems -= 1

        self.total_real_elems -= 1
        self._rebalance()

    def _clean_min_heap_front(self) -> None:
        """While the front of the min_heap was already deleted, remove it from the min_heap"""
        while self.deleted[self.min_heap[0]] > 0:
            self.deleted[heapq.heappop(self.min_heap)] -= 1

    def _clean_max_heap_front(self) -> None:
        """While the front of the max_heap was already deleted, remove it from the max_heap"""
        while self.deleted[-self.max_heap[0]] > 0:
            self.deleted[-heapq.heappop(self.max_heap)] -= 1

    def _rebuild_fully(self) -> None:
        """To guarantee O(log n) amortized insertions and deletions with lazy deletions, we must detect when the number
        of removed elements still in our heap has grown too large: If so, perform an O(n) full rebuild of both heaps
        from scratch, clearing all previously removed elements."""

        # Rebuild heaps, trying to maintain size approximately based on the median
        approx_median: int = self.min_heap[0]

        new_min_heap: List[Union[int, float]] = [math.inf]
        new_max_heap: List[Union[int, float]] = [math.inf]

        for elem in self.max_heap:
            if self.deleted[-elem] > 0:
                self.deleted[-elem] -= 1
                continue
            elif math.isinf(elem):
                continue
            if -elem < approx_median:
                new_max_heap.append(elem)
            elif -elem > approx_median:
                new_min_heap.append(-elem)
            else:
                if len(new_min_heap) - len(new_max_heap) > 1:
                    new_max_heap.append(elem)
                else:
                    new_min_heap.append(-elem)

        for elem in self.min_heap:
            if self.deleted[elem] > 0:
                self.deleted[elem] -= 1
                continue
            elif math.isinf(elem):
                continue

            if elem < approx_median:
                new_max_heap.append(-elem)
            elif elem > approx_median:
                new_min_heap.append(elem)
            else:
                if len(new_min_heap) - len(new_max_heap) > 1:
                    new_max_heap.append(-elem)
                else:
                    new_min_heap.append(elem)

        self.min_heap = new_min_heap
        self.max_heap = new_max_heap

        heapq.heapify(self.min_heap)
        heapq.heapify(self.max_heap)

        self.deleted.clear()
        self.min_real_elems = len(self.min_heap) - 1
        self.max_real_elems = len(self.max_heap) - 1
        self.total_real_elems = self.min_real_elems + self.max_real_elems

        if not (0 <= (self.min_real_elems - self.max_real_elems) <= 1):
            self._rebalance()

    def _need_full_rebuild_check(self) -> bool:
        """Test whether our heaps have a larger fraction of removed elements than allowed"""
        total_size: int = len(self.min_heap) + len(self.max_heap)
        return (self.lazy_deletion_multiplier * (total_size - self.total_real_elems)
               > total_size + self.lazy_deletion_constant)

    def _rebalance(self):
        """ Restore the class invariants:
        1. Front of each heap is infinity (empty heap or sentinel), or a valid element
        2. All elements in self.max_heap have a value <= all elements in self.min_heap
        3. Size (i.e. undeleted elements) of self.min_heap - size of self.max_heap is 0 or 1"""

        if self._need_full_rebuild_check():
            self._rebuild_fully()
            return None

        self._clean_min_heap_front()
        self._clean_max_heap_front()

        while -self.max_heap[0] > self.min_heap[0]:
            if self.min_real_elems - self.max_real_elems <= -1:  # Prefer deleting from max_heap
                self.max_real_elems -= 1
                self.min_real_elems += 1
                heapq.heappush(self.min_heap, -heapq.heappop(self.max_heap))
                self._clean_max_heap_front()

            else:  # Prefer deleting from min_heap
                self.max_real_elems += 1
                self.min_real_elems -= 1
                heapq.heappush(self.max_heap, -heapq.heappop(self.min_heap))
                self._clean_min_heap_front()

        while self.min_real_elems - self.max_real_elems <= -1:  # Need to reduce size of max_heap
            self.max_real_elems -= 1
            self.min_real_elems += 1
            heapq.heappush(self.min_heap, -heapq.heappop(self.max_heap))
            self._clean_max_heap_front()  # Removing front of a heap may place a deleted element in front

        while self.min_real_elems - self.max_real_elems > 1:  # Need to reduce size of min_heap
            self.max_real_elems += 1
            self.min_real_elems -= 1
            heapq.heappush(self.max_heap, -heapq.heappop(self.min_heap))
            self._clean_min_heap_front()  # Removing front of min_heap may place a deleted element in front

        return None

    def calculate_median(self) -> float:
        """Calculate the median in constant time: the median element(s) are always in a heap's front."""
        if self.total_real_elems == 0:
            raise IndexError

        if self.total_real_elems % 2 == 0:
            return (self.min_heap[0] - self.max_heap[0]) / 2.0
        else:
            return self.min_heap[0]
```

Comment: I had considered `SortedList` but they write ["O(log(n)) – **approximate**"](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedList.add), so apparently not really?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode That's correct; looking over the docs, the underlying implementation is a B-Tree limited to 2 levels, so the theoretically optimal complexity is O(n^1/3). There are [performance comparisons](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) which apparently show that it's faster than other publicly available 'sorted mapping' modules for Python, so perhaps it is the most practical solution to the Running Median problem in pure Python.